# Laravel - validation rule for date on update

Tags: laravel

I have this validation rule:

```
'event_start' => 'required|date|after:today',
```

and on creating a model all is fine, this date cannot be before today....

but when a user tries to update the event start date is before today and a validation error pops up....is there a way to adjust this for updating the model? So that when a user updates this rule checks only if it is a date?

UPDATE

this is my only validation check for both create and update:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EventsForm extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        if( auth()->check() )
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [

            'title' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
            'event_start' => 'required|date|after:today',

        ];

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have two separate methods for creating and updating the model? If so just change the validation rule in the updating one. If you use the same validation array for creation and update, you can override the `event_start` key too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have different form request classes for creating and updating events. That’s not to say you can’t use inheritance, though.

If your update method only *slightly* differs from the create method, then you could extend that method’s form request and amend the rules for update:

```php
class CreateEventRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:events',
            'start_date' => 'required|date|after:today',
            'door_time' => 'required|date_format:"H:i:s",
            'location' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

And…

```php
class UpdateEventRequest extends CreateEventRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        // Get ID of event if using route–model binding
        $id = $this->route('event')->getKey();

        // Use array merge to override create event form request’s rules
        return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
            'name' => 'required|unique:events,name,'.$id,
            'start_date' => 'required|date',
        ]);
    }
}
```

You could even push the rules method to an abstract class, and have your create and update form request classes extend *that* class:

```php
abstract class EventFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        // Base event rules
    }
}

class CreateEventRequest extends EventFormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        // Create-specific rules
    }
}

class UpdateEventRequest extends EventFormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        // Update-specific rules
    }
}
```

Comment: can i somehow check in my Request if this is a create or an update?? `$id = $this->route('event')->getKey();` is this it?

Comment: @lewis4u Yes: **You should have different form request classes for creating and updating events.**

Comment: because of one field i think it's not worth it! I have actually over 20 input fields but i didn't show them all here!

Comment: @lewis4u Which is why you should utilise inheritance.

Comment: i just made this `if($this->route('event'))
            $rules['event_start'] = 'required|date'; `and I'm satisfied

Answer (score 2):

If create and update logic is different, just use different validation rules for each method:

```
'event_start' => 'required|date|after:today', // For creating
'event_start' => 'required|date', // For updating
```

Comment: i have made my own request validator, so i use the same for create and update. that's why all the confusion

Comment: So, you're still doing some kind of check to detemrine is this a create or update request. Use it here too.

Comment: how to make that in my request validator now?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the validation rule is located on HttpRequest, then you could change the validation rule to be:

```
'event_start' => 'required|date',
```

And on your controller:

```
public function store(EventRequest $request)
{
       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'event_start' => 'date|after:today',
       ]);

       if($validator->fails())
       {
           return redirect('event/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
       }

       // Save the event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the single method of rules to check if create or update and return array based on that

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [

        'title' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'event_start' => 'required|date|after:today',

    ];
    // $this->route('event') will be null if its create so the defualt one is ok
    if($this->route('event')) {
       // modify rules for edit here 
       $rules['event_start'] => 'required|date';
       $rules['name'] => 'required|unique:events,name,'.$this->route('event')->id;
        // above rules will only be applied if update.
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: yeah it's almost same like mine....so no changes here         `if(\Route::currentRouteName() == 'events.update')
            $rules['event_start'] = 'required|date';
        return $rules; ` except mine has less code :D

Comment: yes, both will work if you inspect route name or route parameter, route name can create problem when named routes are customised but params won't create that problem. :)

Comment: so it's better if i change `if(\Route::currentRouteName() == 'events.update')` with this `if($this->route('event'))`