# How to get the Model id in custom Request class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have made a custom Request for validation and i don't know how to get the Model id on update.

I'm using route model binding and form model binding but this models id is not shown when i hit this Request for validation and i make

```
dd($this);
```

all fields are shown except the model id.

Comment: You need to be more explicit with your code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use route() method on request to retrive the route parameter

`dd($this->route('param_name'));`

if your route is like `/users/{user_id}` then `$this->route('user_id');` will give you the parameter user_id value in request if you have bind custom parameter name in route model binding use that parametername in route() method

for ex. `Route::model('user', App\User::class);` then use `$this->route('user');` to retrive the user model directly.

PS. $this means you should be in your Request class where you define rules() and messages() method.

Comment: yeah that's good....except i need to get ID now. With this `$this->route('event')` i get the whole object....hot to take only id

Comment: i got it now. `$this->route('event')->id` just add ->id at the end and that's it....thank you Sam, you nailed it! ;)

Comment: yes you got it exactly, it gives the actual parameter which is the whole model in your case.. Thanks man. :)

Comment: I have one old question so maybe you can make a better solution if it is possible to have same validation rule for create and update with a validation rule date|after:today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841162/laravel-validation-rule-for-date-on-update

Comment: its very easy one, answering there hold on.

Comment: here is my answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841162/laravel-validation-rule-for-date-on-update/40933349#40933349

Answer (score 1):

For example your route is `/insurance_contract_items/insurance_contract_item/`

You can use `$this->insurance_contract_item` to get your model instance.

As you read on previous answer you can use also `$this->route('insurance_contract_item')`.